# How to overload __new__ with singledispatchmethod and what is the reason it does not work as expected?

Tags: python, initialization, functools, single-dispatch

I want my `__new__` method to behave differently in some cases and wanted to split it into overloaded functions with `singledispatchmethod`.
However this does not work, the overloading functions are never called. What is the reason for that?

```
from functools import singledispatchmethod

class Foo:
     @singledispatchmethod
     def __new__(cls, arg1, **kwargs):
         return "default call"

     @__new__.register(int)
     def _(cls, arg1, **kwargs):
         return "called with int " + str(arg1)

print(Foo("hi"))
# default call
print(Foo(1))
# default call
```

---

As an experiment also used `singledispatch` instead but without success.

Comment: Overloading other methods works like expected, just new behaves differently somehow.

Comment: What happens if you use `@singledispatch` in this case? (If that works, I can't explain why)

Comment: Was wondering what substituting with `singledispatch` does, but it yields the same result and does execute the integer code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might think that `singledispatchmethod` is just a version of `singledispatch` that dispatches based on the second argument instead of the first, but that's not how it works.

Instead, it's [written](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/functools.py#L922) as a class that implements the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) to customize attribute access. When you access a `singledispatchmethod`-decorated method, the attribute access returns a closure object that dispatches based on the first argument to that closure object.

So for example, if a class named `Example` had a singledispatchmethod named `sdm`, then `Example().sdm(1)` would dispatch on the type of 1, but `Example.sdm(Example(), 1)` would dispatch on the type of `Example()`!

---

`__new__` isn't a regular method. It's supposed to be a staticmethod, or at least, it's supposed to be something that behaves like a staticmethod when accessed. (Ordinarily, `type.__new__` would automatically convert `__new__` methods to staticmethods, but it only does that when `__new__` is an ordinary Python function object, and as mentioned, `singledispatchmethod` is implemented as a custom class.)

Particularly, when you do `Foo(1)`, the resulting `__new__` invocation works like `Foo.__new__(Foo, 1)`. It retrieves the `__new__` attribute on `Foo`, then calls whatever it finds with `Foo` and `1` as arguments.

Due to the way `singledispatchmethod` performs dispatch, this dispatches based on the type of `Foo`, not the type of `1`.

---

Ordinarily, if you wanted staticmethod-like behavior from `singledispatchmethod`, the way to get it would be to take advantage of a `singledispatchmethod` feature that lets it wrap other decorators, like so:

```
# This doesn't do what you need.

@functools.singledispatchmethod
@staticmethod
def __new__(cls, arg1, **kwargs):
    ...

@__new__.register(int)
@staticmethod
def _(cls, arg1, **kwargs):
    ...
```

However, this doesn't do anything to fix the problem of which argument we're dispatching on.

Instead, you could write `__new__` as a regular method that delegates to a `singledispatch` helper, and reorder the helper's arguments so the argument you want to dispatch on is in front:

```
import functools

class Foo:
    def __new__(cls, arg1, **kwargs):
        return _new_helper(arg1, cls, **kwargs)

@functools.singledispatch
def _new_helper(arg1, cls, **kwargs):
    return "default call"

@_new_helper.register(int)
def _(arg1, cls, **kwargs):
    return "called with int " + str(arg1)
```

Or, of course, you could ditch the whole singledispatch thing and just write the dispatch handling yourself:

```
import functools

class Foo:
    def __new__(cls, arg1, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(arg1, int):
            return "called with int " + str(arg1)
        else:
            return "default call"
```